# Wierd typed function

Tags: lisp

I  an exercise I have the following function :

```
(defun ifnot (test e1 e2)
   (if test e2 e1))
```

I'm asked to describe the evaluation of the following expression :

```
(ifnot nil "OK" (error "Unexpected test outcome"))
```

I don't know if the problem is about the token "nil" or about the builtin error, may you help me ?

Comment: What problem? The exercise is about when and whether the arguments to a function are evaluated.

Comment: The exercise says evaluating the function call (ifnot nil "OK"...) will produce an error, I'm wondering what the error will be

Comment: Unexpected test outcome?  `(ifnot nil ...)` _should_ work like `(if t ...)` Does it?

Answer (score 2):

`ifnot`, as you've written it, is a function. When a function is evaluated, all of the arguments are evaluated before the function body is evaluated. While the value of `e2` is thrown away in your example, `e2` is still evaluated, and so `error` is still called. If it were a macro instead, then it would work as you seem to intend:

```
(defmacro ifnot (test e1 e2)
  `(if ,test ,e2 ,e1))
```

This way, the code

```
(ifnot nil "OK" (error "Unexpected test outcome"))
```

is replaced with this at compile time:

```
(if nil (error "Unexpected test outcome") "OK")
```